# How to pass data from view model to javascript function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

For example I have the following model which I am passing a list of to the view:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

In my view I have the following:

```
@model List<ExampleViewModel>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var x in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => x.name)
            </td>
            <td> 
                <input type="button" onclick="edit();" value="Edit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(x) {
        window.location = "/Home/Edit?id=" + x
    }
</script>
```

What I am having trouble with is passing x.id to the edit() function. I expected:

```
<input type="button" onclick="edit(@x.id);" value="Edit">
```

to work but it did not.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="button" onclick="edit(@x.id);" value="Edit">
```

Comment: Unterminated string constant

Comment: This actually works, I was missing a ; in the script I was calling. Visual studio thinks that the onclick is a syntax error but when it is running it works. Thank you. This is actually the same as I had initially thought it would be!

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend you to use data slash atributes, and use something like jQuery to handle events, and use the data slash attributes.

A data slash attribute is simply an attribute whose name starts with "data-". You can define as many of theses attributes as you need, on any element, an all browsers will support them.

```
<input type="button" onclick="edit" data-id="@x.id" value="Edit">
```

When the edit method is executed, you can access the element (using this), and them with jQuery you can get the attributes values lie this:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

You can even go further, and remove the "onclick=edit" part. Then use jQuery to susbscribe the click event to all the elements with the required attribute, like this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  // this happens when all the page has been loaded in the browser (ready)
  $('input[data-id]').on('click', function() { 
    // find the input elements with the "data-id" attr, and, when 'click'ed...
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    //get the attribute value and do whatever you want with it...
  });
});
```

*NOTE: you can use `var id = $(this).data('id');` as an alternative.

This technique is known as "unobtrusive JavaScript". To do this, of course, you need to include jQuery in your page. Please, start using jQuery (or any other library) tha will make things easier for you. if you use it, I'd recommend you to use "namespaced" names for the attributes to avoid collisions. I.e, something like "data-mynamespace-id", using whatever makes sense as your namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="edit('@(x.id)');" value="Edit">
```

Note that if you want to pass variable from your ViewModel to javascript you should use qoutes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = '@Model[0].x';
</script>
```

Also you can try declaration of edit function before table.