# Creating a Tri-State checkbox component for blazor

Tags: checkbox, blazor

```html
<input @bind="Checked" type="checkbox" @onclick="eventArgs => { onclick(); }" indeterminate="@indeterminate" class="checkbox-input">

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public bool? selected { get; set; } = null;

    public bool indeterminate { get; set; }

    public bool Checked { get; set; }

    public void onclick()
    {



        selected = selected == null ? true : selected == true ? new bool?() : false;



        Checked = selected == null || selected == false;
        indeterminate = selected == null;

    }
}
```

This doesn't produce the desired result

The checkbox is always either checked or unchecked, never indeterminate.

Any ideas?

Comment: indeterminate is not settable in HTML and not supported by Blazor. You will need some JS interop, or use a component  library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this simple component in .NET core 3.1+.
Here is a [fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/qsi0ruka).

The css is from bootstrap, needed to display an empty box, a checked one and a box "full" to indicate the states 0,1,-1 (can change these values easily):

```
<style>
    [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] { display: inline-block; width: 14px; height: 14px; margin-top: 1px; *margin-right: .3em; line-height: 14px; vertical-align: text-top; background-image: url(/img/glyphicons-halflings.png); background-position: 14px 14px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
    .bootstrap-checkbox { display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 13px; height: 13px; border: 1px solid #000; -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
        .bootstrap-checkbox i { position: absolute; left: -2px; top: -3px; }
    .icon-stop { background-position: -312px -72px; }
    .icon-check { background-position: -288px 0px; }
</style>
```

and this is the blazor component:

```
<div @ref=checkboxElement class="bootstrap-checkbox" @onclick="(e) => OnClick(e)"><i class="@ImgClass"></i></div>@Description

@code {

    public ElementReference checkboxElement { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public bool? Checked { get; set; }
    public string ImgClass { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Value = Checked switch { null => -1, true => 1, false => 0 };
        ImgClass = Value switch { -1 => "icon-stop", 1 => "icon-check", _ => "" };
    }

    public void OnClick(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (ImgClass)
        {
            case "":
                ImgClass = "icon-check";
                Value = 1;
                break;
            case "icon-check":
                ImgClass = "icon-stop";
                Value = -1;
                break;
            case "icon-stop":
                ImgClass = "";
                Value = 0;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JS interop

Create a simple script

```
<script>
var auxiliarDOM = auxiliarDOM || {};
auxiliarDOM.setValue = function (element, property,value) {
    element[property] = value;
}
</script>
```

Then in blazor you can has a ElementRef

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
<input @ref="checkRef" type="checkbox" />

private ElementReference checkRef;

//this make the check indeterminate
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("auxiliarDOM.setValue", checkRef, "indeterminate", true);
//this make the check no indeterminate
await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("auxiliarDOM.setValue", checkRef, "indeterminate", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

### Tri-state checkbox component, based on Eliseo's answer:

Working example: [Blazor fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/xnc9tubr)

JS to set the `indeterminate` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setElementProperty(element, property, value) {
        element[property] = value;
    }
</script>
```

CheckBox.razor file:

```
<input @ref=elementRef id="@elementId" type="checkbox" checked="@isChecked" @onchange="OnChange"/>
<label for="@elementId">@ChildContent</label>
```

CheckBox.razor.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.JSInterop;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public partial class CheckBox
{
    [Inject]
    IJSRuntime jsRuntime { get; set; } = null!;

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public bool? Checked { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<bool?> CheckedChanged { get; set; }

    private bool isChecked;

    private ElementReference elementRef;

    private string elementId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    private async Task OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Checked = Checked switch
        {
            false => true,
            true => null,
            null => false,
        };

        isChecked = Checked != false;

        bool indet = Checked == null;

        await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("setElementProperty", elementRef, "indeterminate", indet);

        await CheckedChanged.InvokeAsync(Checked);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not properly working when the initial isChecked (in Blazor fiddle) is null or true. To fix need move the InvokeVoidAsync(...) to OnAfterRenderAsync(...).